# How can I fix this Python automation error?

Tags: python, api, installation, automation, python-requests

I switched between python interpreters and pip installed instabot on the desktop and inside of the projects virtual environment. Still getting this error.

```
2023-02-22 08:50:09,337 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2023-02-22 08:50:09,353 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2023-02-22 08:50:09,704 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2023-02-22 08:50:09,705 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
```

Comment: It looks like your bot has been blocked for too many requests. Check rate limit of the API. You are restricted from new requests in next 5 minutes